# How could I improve my code

Tags: python

Could I have some tips on how to improve my code?

This is the code I would like to improve

```
timetable =(input('Please enter a number: ')
  if timetable ==('11')
    print(('Please enter a number less than 10 / equal to 10")) 
      for t in range(0, 16):
        print(str(t)+" timetable "=str(t)+" is "+str(t*t)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to tell you exactly what to fix, because that is not how to learn. But here are some issues:

1. If statements need a colon at the end
2. Printing multiple things in one statement require a comma or plus sign between each of the things
3. A string can begin and end with ' or ", but they need to be the same at the beginning or end.
4. Won't give an error, but easy on the brackets, you have way more brackets than you need.
5. Don't tab out every line

Generally, read the error message, see what line it applies to, google the name of the error, and, you know, work it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors with the syntax in your code. I'd recommend taking a look back over some introductory Python material to ensure you understand the meaning of brackets, colons, etc.

Note that

1. You don't need to put brackets around a single string. That will only confuse matters.
2. Try to leave spaces between your operators (`+`, `/`, `==` etc.) It will make your code a lot easier to read and it will be easier to see whether you have the operators in the right place.
3. Brackets must always match up: if you open them, you have to close them.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you have to learn about indentation and other things as given in the other answers. But, if you still want to have your code rewritten, you can see the below, if you have the python interpreter, when you run the file, you'll see the error on the corresponding line.

```
timetable = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
if timetable > 10:
    print("Please enter a number less than 10 / equal to 10") 
for t in range(0, 16):
    print(str(t)+" timetable ="+str(t)+" is "+str(t*t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your putting unnecessary brackets around most of your variables

I would also recommend you use an integer input for numbers

```
timetable = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
```

From your code it seems you want an input < or = to 10

```
if timetable > 10:
    print("Please enter a number less than or equal to 10")
```

Move your for loop outside the if statement

Also use the .format function to format text into a string

```
for t in range(0, 16):
    print("{} timetable {} is {}".format(t, t, (t*t)))
```

All together you end up with something like

```
timetable = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

if timetable > 10:
    print("Please enter a number less than or equal to 10")

for t in range(0, 16):
    print("{} timetable = {} is {}".format(t, t, (t*t)))
```